# Dual-screen Flash - does it work?

Tags: multiple-monitors, flash, fullscreen

Flash 10.2 brought the ability to full-screen and not exit out of it when using another screen (see [this article](http://techie-buzz.com/tech-news/flash-10-2-released.html)). At least it did for Windows.

I've never gotten dual-screen Flash to work like this for me.. ever. Clicking on my other monitor while a video is full-screened still exits out of full-screen mode. Am I doing something wrong here? I've not seen any other posts on this issue, both on Ask Ubuntu and in the Ubuntu forums..

I typically run Chrome; current setup is Ubuntu 11.04 x64. I use Flash-Aid for Firefox to keep my Flash up to date.

Any help to get this functionality to work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, the [MaximizeFlash](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljjmflmcnaigbhnheldbdbplkbhngnl) extension for Chrome works. It maximizes any Flash video to fill your browser window. This doesn't solve the problem directly, but makes it less annoying.